# Populating div with the last three characters from a form input text element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I have this code that populates the div with the form input data:

```
var div = $('div')[0];
$('input').bind('keyup change', function() {
    div.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

but I only want to extract the three last characters from the input field not all characters. How can I make this happen using jQuery?

Thanx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScripts build-in method `.substr()` for that:

```
var div = $('div')[0];
$('input').bind('keyup change', function() {
    var val = this.value,
        valLength = val.length;
    div.innerHTML = valLength < 3 ? val : val.substr(valLength - 3, 3);
    // check if the value has less than three chracters. If yes return the plain value, if not return the less three characters.
});
```

`.substr()` cuts out a part of the string. It accepts two arguments. The first one determinates at what position you want the substring to begin and the second one says how long it should be.

Comment: I thought I'd test this with a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/kFwcj/) to find out if a guard statement was needed for short strings (ie if val.length<3). It came up with the weird result that on typing A,B,C it displayed "A", then just "B", then "ABC" and kept working from there on out... Not sure why that is but thought I'd note it as relevant (this is on FF, works fine in IE).

Comment: @Chris You are right! I added a little fix, now it works. Note: Caching the length is probably micro-optimization but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str =this.value; 
div.innerHTML = str.substring(str.length-3,str.length);
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/QwSJF/)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
div.innerHTML = this.value.slice(-3);
```

`slice()` takes two arguments; the `begin` index and the `end` index. If either is negative, the index is takes as an offset from the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) on value as follows:

```
div.innerHTML = this.value.substr(-3);
```

Although as [Microsoft JScript doesn't support a negative *start* value](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0esxc5wy.aspx), you may prefer:

```
div.innerHTML = this.value.substr(this.value.length-3);
```

One additional note, I would never use 'innerHTML' with a user input value... it gives needlessly elevated access to the target element in your case. Instead (as you're using jQuery), use:

```
div.text(this.value.substr(-3));
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with using `.html()` for user input. A user can always edit the Markup anyways. Press F12 in any webkit browser.

Comment: Its just bad practice to allow a user interface to inject [whatever] into a webpage when there is no need. Web Developer tools are there for that purpose, where as I doubt the OP's interface is being designed to purposely allow a user to inject code. Even though the risk may be medium to minimal, security should never be handled with a view of 'it will probably never be an issue'.

Comment: You are right `.text()` is more efficient if he just needs to insert text. But it's definitly not *a hackers dream*, as you can always insert custom markup. As long as he doesn't save it like that on the serverside and then echoes it this is no problem.

Comment: @dotweb depending on how the field is populated this might allow to change the source *other* users might see after clicking on a crafty constructed link. Given it's only a 3-digit-window of opportunity this might be insubstantial here but every code might be reused and changed at sometime in the future (see Mars Surveyor mission failure). If there is a safe and easy way of doing something, there shouldn't be a reason to take the unsafe route.

Comment: @dotweb I agree that my note on security is a little too sensationalist and have toned it down with an edit. I do this as the web is full of JavaScript code which is needlessly vulnerable. I am a firm believer in the fact that 'it's highly unlikely anything can happen' is a reason for shortcutting out security.

Answer (score 0):

var txt = "string";
txt = txt.substring(txt.length-3);

http://jsfiddle.net/WyT5j/